# Как узнать с какой странице пришел юзер?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

У меня есть элемент который показан на всех страницах сайта, там есть кнопка. Когда юзер кликает на неё, то попадает в меню настроек. Как я могу узнать с какой страницы он пришел чтобы обработать и настроить кнопку возврата.

Сейчас при нажатии на кнопку возврата, просто идет редирект на главную страницу.

```
   $(document).on('click', '#back-btn', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Task")';
    });
```

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer`

Comment: @igor можно немного поподробней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (Request.UrlReferrer != null) {
  window.location.href = '@Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri';
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

А `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];` чем не устраивает? Там хранится url откуда пришли.

Верней у JS это  [document.referrer;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

Answer (score 0):

document.referrer выдаст только доменное имя от куда пришли, но не скажет полного пути. Например если переход был с mysite.com/blog, то мы получим по данному методу только mysite.com

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! это же комментарий к [первому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653464/178576), правильно? значит, стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос